# Error while importing raylib python library

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, raylib

I am trying to install raylib on macOS M1.
I tried pip3 install raylib and also brew install raylib, but both installed succesfully but when i import raylib it shows me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arianmalmir/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyray import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyray/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from raylib import rl, ffi
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/raylib/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._raylib_cffi import ffi, lib as rl
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/raylib/_raylib_cffi.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/raylib/_raylib_cffi.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/_raylib_cffi.abi3.so' (no such file)
```

Comment: Does https://pypi.org/project/pyraylib/ work for you?